# Sprinboot Jackson Date Serialize

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

i face a litle problem with Jackson on springboot web, i'm expecting this kind of response.

```
{
  'date': 'string of date'
}
```

but i get back this

```
[
  0: java.sql.date,
  1: long number of timestamp
]
```

please how to configure springboot to avoid this?

```
    @Configuration
    public class BootConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule() {
            return new JavaTimeModule();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Jdk8Module jdk8TimeModule() {
            return new Jdk8Module();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public CoreJackson2Module coreJackson2Module() {
            return new CoreJackson2Module();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module authorizationServerJackson2Module(){
            return new OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module();
        }
    
    
        public List<Module> securityModules(){
            ClassLoader classLoader = JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.class.getClassLoader();
            return SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(classLoader);
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();
            mapper.registerModule(coreJackson2Module());
            mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule());
            mapper.registerModule(jdk8TimeModule());
            mapper.registerModules(securityModules());
            mapper.registerModule(authorizationServerJackson2Module());
            mapper.addMixIn(UserPrincipal.class, Object.class);
            return mapper;
        }
}
```

this is the controller method where

```
@GetMapping(value = "/authentications", params = {"pge","lmt", "slug"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getLastLogins(
        Authentication authentication,
        @RequestParam("lmt")Integer limit,
        @RequestParam("pge")Integer page,
        @RequestParam("slug")String slug){
            return  new ResponseEntity<>(loginManager.findAllAuthentications(authentication.getName(),slug,limit,page), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

and this is the model containing the properties i try to get back

```
    @Data
    public class User implements Serializable {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Date date;
        private Role role;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: thanks for reacting so quickly ok lemme add somme config codes

Answer (score 0):

The only issue which i see might be intefering with your ObjectMapper is the 2 extra modules which are added.

```
mapper.registerModules(securityModules());
mapper.registerModule(authorizationServerJackson2Module());
```

try removing these 2 and then try again.